# Swift code error code 1 during compiling code

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing

I'm building a simple app with Xcode in Swift code.

So if I try to start this application, I have this error:

```
CopySwiftLibs /Users/michele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ArduinoHomeKit_bis-bltyyfimprkpesgvsgewynvmqopd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ArduinoHomeKit_bis.app (in target: ArduinoHomeKit_bis)
    cd /Users/michele/Dropbox/workspace-xcode/progetto\ xcode/ArduinoHomeKit_bis
    export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
    export DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    export SDKROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.1.sdk
    builtin-swiftStdLibTool --copy --verbose --sign 472FF96119E4B61901337B11D4C5F5E832C0E2AC --scan-executable /Users/michele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ArduinoHomeKit_bis-bltyyfimprkpesgvsgewynvmqopd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ArduinoHomeKit_bis.app/ArduinoHomeKit_bis --scan-folder /Users/michele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ArduinoHomeKit_bis-bltyyfimprkpesgvsgewynvmqopd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ArduinoHomeKit_bis.app/Frameworks --scan-folder /Users/michele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ArduinoHomeKit_bis-bltyyfimprkpesgvsgewynvmqopd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ArduinoHomeKit_bis.app/PlugIns --platform iphoneos --toolchain /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain --destination /Users/michele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ArduinoHomeKit_bis-bltyyfimprkpesgvsgewynvmqopd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ArduinoHomeKit_bis.app/Frameworks --strip-bitcode --resource-destination /Users/michele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ArduinoHomeKit_bis-bltyyfimprkpesgvsgewynvmqopd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ArduinoHomeKit_bis.app --resource-library libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib --strip-bitcode-tool /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip --emit-dependency-info /Users/michele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ArduinoHomeKit_bis-bltyyfimprkpesgvsgewynvmqopd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArduinoHomeKit_bis.build/Debug-iphoneos/ArduinoHomeKit_bis.build/SwiftStdLibToolInputDependencies.dep

Requested Swift ABI version based on scanned binaries: 6
Copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib to /Users/michele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ArduinoHomeKit_bis-bltyyfimprkpesgvsgewynvmqopd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ArduinoHomeKit_bis.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib -r -o /Users/michele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ArduinoHomeKit_bis-bltyyfimprkpesgvsgewynvmqopd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ArduinoHomeKit_bis.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib
Copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftCore.dylib to /Users/michele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ArduinoHomeKit_bis-bltyyfimprkpesgvsgewynvmqopd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ArduinoHomeKit_bis.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftCore.dylib -r -o /Users/michele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ArduinoHomeKit_bis-bltyyfimprkpesgvsgewynvmqopd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ArduinoHomeKit_bis.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
Copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib to /Users/michele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ArduinoHomeKit_bis-bltyyfimprkpesgvsgewynvmqopd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ArduinoHomeKit_bis.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib -r -o /Users/michele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ArduinoHomeKit_bis-bltyyfimprkpesgvsgewynvmqopd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ArduinoHomeKit_bis.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib
Copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib to /Users/michele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ArduinoHomeKit_bis-bltyyfimprkpesgvsgewynvmqopd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ArduinoHomeKit_bis.app/Frameworks/libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib -r -o /Users/michele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ArduinoHomeKit_bis-bltyyfimprkpesgvsgewynvmqopd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ArduinoHomeKit_bis.app/Frameworks/libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib
Copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftos.dylib to /Users/michele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ArduinoHomeKit_bis-bltyyfimprkpesgvsgewynvmqopd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ArduinoHomeKit_bis.app/Frameworks/libswiftos.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftos.dylib -r -o /Users/michele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ArduinoHomeKit_bis-bltyyfimprkpesgvsgewynvmqopd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ArduinoHomeKit_bis.app/Frameworks/libswiftos.dylib
Copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftCoreImage.dylib to /Users/michele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ArduinoHomeKit_bis-bltyyfimprkpesgvsgewynvmqopd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ArduinoHomeKit_bis.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreImage.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftCoreImage.dylib -r -o /Users/michele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ArduinoHomeKit_bis-bltyyfimprkpesgvsgewynvmqopd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ArduinoHomeKit_bis.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreImage.dylib
Copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftUIKit.dylib to /Users/michele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ArduinoHomeKit_bis-bltyyfimprkpesgvsgewynvmqopd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ArduinoHomeKit_bis.app/Frameworks/libswiftUIKit.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftUIKit.dylib -r -o /Users/michele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ArduinoHomeKit_bis-bltyyfimprkpesgvsgewynvmqopd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ArduinoHomeKit_bis.app/Frameworks/libswiftUIKit.dylib
Copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftDispatch.dylib to /Users/michele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ArduinoHomeKit_bis-bltyyfimprkpesgvsgewynvmqopd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ArduinoHomeKit_bis.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftDispatch.dylib -r -o /Users/michele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ArduinoHomeKit_bis-bltyyfimprkpesgvsgewynvmqopd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ArduinoHomeKit_bis.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib
Copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftCoreData.dylib to /Users/michele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ArduinoHomeKit_bis-bltyyfimprkpesgvsgewynvmqopd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ArduinoHomeKit_bis.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreData.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftCoreData.dylib -r -o /Users/michele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ArduinoHomeKit_bis-bltyyfimprkpesgvsgewynvmqopd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ArduinoHomeKit_bis.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreData.dylib
Copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftQuartzCore.dylib to /Users/michele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ArduinoHomeKit_bis-bltyyfimprkpesgvsgewynvmqopd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ArduinoHomeKit_bis.app/Frameworks/libswiftQuartzCore.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftQuartzCore.dylib -r -o /Users/michele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ArduinoHomeKit_bis-bltyyfimprkpesgvsgewynvmqopd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ArduinoHomeKit_bis.app/Frameworks/libswiftQuartzCore.dylib
Copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib to /Users/michele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ArduinoHomeKit_bis-bltyyfimprkpesgvsgewynvmqopd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ArduinoHomeKit_bis.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib -r -o /Users/michele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ArduinoHomeKit_bis-bltyyfimprkpesgvsgewynvmqopd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ArduinoHomeKit_bis.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib
Copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftFoundation.dylib to /Users/michele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ArduinoHomeKit_bis-bltyyfimprkpesgvsgewynvmqopd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ArduinoHomeKit_bis.app/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftFoundation.dylib -r -o /Users/michele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ArduinoHomeKit_bis-bltyyfimprkpesgvsgewynvmqopd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ArduinoHomeKit_bis.app/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib
Copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftMetal.dylib to /Users/michele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ArduinoHomeKit_bis-bltyyfimprkpesgvsgewynvmqopd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ArduinoHomeKit_bis.app/Frameworks/libswiftMetal.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftMetal.dylib -r -o /Users/michele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ArduinoHomeKit_bis-bltyyfimprkpesgvsgewynvmqopd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ArduinoHomeKit_bis.app/Frameworks/libswiftMetal.dylib
Copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftDarwin.dylib to /Users/michele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ArduinoHomeKit_bis-bltyyfimprkpesgvsgewynvmqopd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ArduinoHomeKit_bis.app/Frameworks/libswiftDarwin.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftDarwin.dylib -r -o /Users/michele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ArduinoHomeKit_bis-bltyyfimprkpesgvsgewynvmqopd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ArduinoHomeKit_bis.app/Frameworks/libswiftDarwin.dylib
Copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib to /Users/michele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ArduinoHomeKit_bis-bltyyfimprkpesgvsgewynvmqopd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ArduinoHomeKit_bis.app/libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib
Probing signature of /Users/michele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ArduinoHomeKit_bis-bltyyfimprkpesgvsgewynvmqopd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ArduinoHomeKit_bis.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib
/usr/bin/codesign -r- --display /Users/michele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ArduinoHomeKit_bis-bltyyfimprkpesgvsgewynvmqopd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ArduinoHomeKit_bis.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib
/Users/michele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ArduinoHomeKit_bis-bltyyfimprkpesgvsgewynvmqopd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ArduinoHomeKit_bis.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib: code object is not signed at all

Codesigning /Users/michele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ArduinoHomeKit_bis-bltyyfimprkpesgvsgewynvmqopd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ArduinoHomeKit_bis.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign 472FF96119E4B61901337B11D4C5F5E832C0E2AC --verbose /Users/michele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ArduinoHomeKit_bis-bltyyfimprkpesgvsgewynvmqopd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ArduinoHomeKit_bis.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib
/Users/michele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ArduinoHomeKit_bis-bltyyfimprkpesgvsgewynvmqopd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ArduinoHomeKit_bis.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib: errSecInternalComponent

error: Failed with exit code 1
```

Error with code 1. What is the problem ?

Comment: try to delete your derived data and clean build

Comment: I have try to clean and rebuild the application.

Comment: delete the derived data from the folder it self , also try legacy build

Comment: https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2015/12/how-to-delete-derived-data-and-clean.html

Comment: Probably Swift 5 written code. Try to clean your Xcode & delete derived data.

Comment: It is very strange because if I try to start the app on my iPhone 5s, I get this error. If I try to start the app on simulatore iPhone 5s, I don't have never error.

Comment: Looks like a code signing issue, not a code problem.

Comment: @bircastri Do you have a paid developer account?

Comment: As @rmaddy said, it looks like a code signing error returning errsecinternalcomponent. Check whether this solution works for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51649727/codesign-returned-errsecinternalcomponent-in-high-sierra/53552270#53552270