# Xcode Command CodeSign failed with non zero when deploying to device

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode10, codesign

I received this error when trying to deploy application to device. I am using Xcode 10.1 with free developer account. In signing section I set personal team with signing certificate iPhone Developer. I can ran the app in iOS simulator but not run in real device.
[image]

Exact error message:

```
CodeSign /Users/***/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/****-eqztbodhqkugrwevuvkmzysmcvdj/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/****\ Mobile.app (in target: ******)

cd /Users/***/Projects/**********/platforms/ios

export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate



Signing Identity:     "iPhone Developer:******@*****.com (QALD7Y5PCU)"

Provisioning Profile: "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: com.***.****"

                      (7475de4a-3ae3-4798-9c9c-a8e65a1bc1b9)



/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign 55DEB33A3DF3254D66B1AC6CEACB052CABCF3644 --entitlements /Users/***/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/************-eqztbodhqkugrwevuvkmzysmcvdj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/****\ Mobile.build/Debug-iphoneos/****\ Mobile.build/****\ Mobile.app.xcent --timestamp=none /Users/****/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/**********-eqztbodhqkugrwevuvkmzysmcvdj/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/****\ Mobile.app



/Users/****/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/********-eqztbodhqkugrwevuvkmzysmcvdj/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/**** Mobile.app: errSecInternalComponent

Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code
```

[image]

Comment: Automatically manage signing checkbox is checked ? if not do check mark it.

Comment: Yes, it's checked.

Comment: can you upload the photo of your code signing?

Comment: I added the photo.

Comment: What exact error message you got?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Codesign returned errSecInternalComponent in High Sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51649727/codesign-returned-errsecinternalcomponent-in-high-sierra)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got same issue , my certificates was created automatically but Device Udid does not create.
then check your device Udid is exist on your Apple developer Account and also check your Bundle identifier?

// hope its works for you thanks

Comment: This is correct, my device ID was not associated with my developer account. Thanks!

Comment: how someone can add UDID with free developer account ?

Comment: yes it is not possible on free account, apple does not give permission to create certificates on free account,In this case his code run on simulator but not in device , so my answer is ,check your bundle or device udid is exist or not, in free account how can we add device udid, am sure its not possible

Answer (score 2):

Your code signing for free account should look like this
[image: Check this]

Comment: It looks something like that, see the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this error today, and it resolved with steps below.

1 Deleted newly added image from Asset folder.
2 Restarted my mac computer. 
3 Re-launched xCode and did a clean build.

Comment: reboot OSX is awesome !!!

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this error, in my experience I am trying to run my app in a device which is not registered in my provisioning profile. To resolve this, you need to make sure you are not using a production provisioning profile because you can not assign a device there. Use development provisioning profile, assign the device in that provisioning profile, download the provisioning profile and double click it. Build again and it should work.