# Trying to archive my build gives a PhaseScriptExecution error

Tags: ios, swift

I can't archive my build it gives the next `errorCommand`:

> PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

I am not able to run the build in device while run using the provision profile. Is the issue related to a provision profile?

I've tried to reinstall all pods, but still I can't archive a build successfully.

Comment: Can you please provide screenshot of error or something? As the question looks a little bit confusing at this point.

Comment: rsync --delete -av --filter P .*.?????? --filter "- CVS/" --filter "- .svn/" --filter "- .git/" --filter "- .hg/" --filter "- Headers" --filter "- PrivateHeaders" --filter "- Modules" "/Users/semantic/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyBenefits360-cfcqsaenoctiuxfhacyjqmbpldns/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GoogleUtilities/GoogleUtilities.framework" "/Users/semantic/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyBenefits360-cfcqsaenoctiuxfhacyjqmbpldns/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app/Frameworks

Comment: When I registerd new app ID and create certificate and provision profile, this issue occured

Comment: Xcode shows this error - Code Signing /Users/Name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp360-cfcqsaenoctiuxfhacyjqmbpldns/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp360.app/Frameworks/GoogleUtilities.framework with Identity iPhone Developer: DeveloperName (TeamID)
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign BB26B44F00DE478072C3C388652575FDFC599714  --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements 
--errSecInternalComponent
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Comment: which Xcode version you used? it is 10.0 or newer?

Comment: see this post, it may helps you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51174105/pods-root-swiftlint-swiftlint-causes-command-phasescriptexecution-failed-w/54415718#54415718

Comment: I am using Xcode 10

Comment: I already try this but no success

Comment: check this whether it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51649727/codesign-returned-errsecinternalcomponent-in-high-sierra/53552270#53552270