# Xcode 10.0: Failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode10

```
CopySwiftLibs /Users/90301207/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/codeChecker-hcddnntogbbtbqecesokhznmpcsq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/codeChecker.app (in target: codeChecker)
    cd /Users/90301207/Desktop/IOS\ Development/IOS\ Projects/codeChecker
    export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
    export DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    export SDKROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.0.sdk
    builtin-swiftStdLibTool --copy --verbose --sign AC89DB35766AAF3EAFB57F70F3F3167E4AC07C96 --scan-executable /Users/90301207/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/codeChecker-hcddnntogbbtbqecesokhznmpcsq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/codeChecker.app/codeChecker --scan-folder /Users/90301207/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/codeChecker-hcddnntogbbtbqecesokhznmpcsq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/codeChecker.app/Frameworks --scan-folder /Users/90301207/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/codeChecker-hcddnntogbbtbqecesokhznmpcsq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/codeChecker.app/PlugIns --platform iphoneos --toolchain /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain --destination /Users/90301207/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/codeChecker-hcddnntogbbtbqecesokhznmpcsq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/codeChecker.app/Frameworks --strip-bitcode --resource-destination /Users/90301207/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/codeChecker-hcddnntogbbtbqecesokhznmpcsq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/codeChecker.app --resource-library libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib --strip-bitcode-tool /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip --emit-dependency-info /Users/90301207/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/codeChecker-hcddnntogbbtbqecesokhznmpcsq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/codeChecker.build/Debug-iphoneos/codeChecker.build/SwiftStdLibToolInputDependencies.dep

Requested Swift ABI version based on scanned binaries: 6
libswiftObjectiveC.dylib is up to date at /Users/90301207/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/codeChecker-hcddnntogbbtbqecesokhznmpcsq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/codeChecker.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib
libswiftCoreImage.dylib is up to date at /Users/90301207/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/codeChecker-hcddnntogbbtbqecesokhznmpcsq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/codeChecker.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreImage.dylib
libswiftUIKit.dylib is up to date at /Users/90301207/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/codeChecker-hcddnntogbbtbqecesokhznmpcsq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/codeChecker.app/Frameworks/libswiftUIKit.dylib
libswiftMetal.dylib is up to date at /Users/90301207/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/codeChecker-hcddnntogbbtbqecesokhznmpcsq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/codeChecker.app/Frameworks/libswiftMetal.dylib
libswiftCore.dylib is up to date at /Users/90301207/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/codeChecker-hcddnntogbbtbqecesokhznmpcsq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/codeChecker.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
libswiftFoundation.dylib is up to date at /Users/90301207/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/codeChecker-hcddnntogbbtbqecesokhznmpcsq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/codeChecker.app/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib
libswiftos.dylib is up to date at /Users/90301207/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/codeChecker-hcddnntogbbtbqecesokhznmpcsq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/codeChecker.app/Frameworks/libswiftos.dylib
libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib is up to date at /Users/90301207/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/codeChecker-hcddnntogbbtbqecesokhznmpcsq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/codeChecker.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib
libswiftDarwin.dylib is up to date at /Users/90301207/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/codeChecker-hcddnntogbbtbqecesokhznmpcsq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/codeChecker.app/Frameworks/libswiftDarwin.dylib
libswiftDispatch.dylib is up to date at /Users/90301207/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/codeChecker-hcddnntogbbtbqecesokhznmpcsq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/codeChecker.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib
libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib is up to date at /Users/90301207/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/codeChecker-hcddnntogbbtbqecesokhznmpcsq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/codeChecker.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib
libswiftQuartzCore.dylib is up to date at /Users/90301207/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/codeChecker-hcddnntogbbtbqecesokhznmpcsq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/codeChecker.app/Frameworks/libswiftQuartzCore.dylib
libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib is up to date at /Users/90301207/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/codeChecker-hcddnntogbbtbqecesokhznmpcsq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/codeChecker.app/libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib
Probing signature of /Users/90301207/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/codeChecker-hcddnntogbbtbqecesokhznmpcsq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/codeChecker.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib
/usr/bin/codesign -r- --display /Users/90301207/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/codeChecker-hcddnntogbbtbqecesokhznmpcsq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/codeChecker.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib
/Users/90301207/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/codeChecker-hcddnntogbbtbqecesokhznmpcsq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/codeChecker.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib: code object is not signed at all

Codesigning /Users/90301207/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/codeChecker-hcddnntogbbtbqecesokhznmpcsq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/codeChecker.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign AC89DB35766AAF3EAFB57F70F3F3167E4AC07C96 --verbose /Users/90301207/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/codeChecker-hcddnntogbbtbqecesokhznmpcsq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/codeChecker.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib
/Users/90301207/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/codeChecker-hcddnntogbbtbqecesokhznmpcsq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/codeChecker.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib: errSecInternalComponent

error: Failed with exit code 1
```

This error keeps throwing for any of my apps when I try to run them on my iPhone 7 or iPad 6

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/51069480/1187415 (try locking the keychain and unlocking it again).

Comment: Thank you, Martin. That seemed to work.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you having an Code Signing issue. Try check "Automatically manage signing", clean and build the project and try again.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoWYv.png)