# Xcode suddenly runs into code signing error

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, code-signing-certificate

My xcode suddenly runs into a code signing error when trying to build my app (for now just to launch on the debug device). Previously it was working but now it just fails with `Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1`, there is no further output.

I am aware of the technical notes at https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2407/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40014991-CH1-ENSURE_YOUR_PROJECT_OPTS_INTO_AUTOMATIC_PROVISIONING but as i dont have any of the error messages described i am stuck.

- i did check that automatic provisioning is enabled
- i did log in and log out of my account
- i did reinstall the certificate on my pc
- i did restart xcode
- i did check the signing settings

  - [x] Automatically manage signing
  - Correct team selected
  - Provisioning Profile: Xcode managed profile
  - Signing Certificate: Correct development certificate

Now i don't know how i can resolve this anymore.

Comment: Looks like similar question asked :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24023639/xcode-command-usr-bin-codesign-failed-with-exit-code-1-errsecinternalcomponen

Comment: There are a lot of similar questions. But in this question the person gets further output `CSSM_SignData returned ...`, i don't have any of those.

Comment: did you do lock and unlock process  login from keychain ?