# errSecInternalComponent error while building iOS project

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have Xamarin.Forms project. Getting compile time error in iOS project when I build it.

> /Users/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/TestIPA.iOS/20ea5664acbc74b08c8c166bd741fce2/bin/iPhone/Release/TestApp.iOS.app:
>   errSecInternalComponent

My Visual studio is connected to Mac machine. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51069480/4984832

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Go to Keychain Access -> Toggle once the lock/unlock icon for Login -> Keep it at Unlock state -> This fixed my issue.*

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 - I checked my profile stuff, and that I was logged into my Apple account from Visual Studio -> Preferences -> Accounts

Step 2 - let Visual Studio do the signing for me enabling the “Automatic Provisioning” that you can find & setup via left-click Info.Plist -> Application tab

Step 3 - To make sure my keychain login chain wasn’t locked, I ran the following in my Terminal:
$ security unlock-keychain login.keychain
(followed by entering my computer password in the dialogue that appears)

Step 4 - I restarted my MacBook Pro

Step 5 - After restart, I removed the USB cable from my phone to my MacBook, and re-inserted it

Step 6 - I cleaned my entire solution

Step 7 - Then I ran the project to build and compile it for my device