# Jenkins jobs not working after revoking Distribution certificate in Remote Machine

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, remote-server, ad-hoc-distribution

I have been facing an issue with Jenkins in building my iOS jobs. Recently our distribution certificate has been expired and we have revoked it and imported the same cert into Remote Machine. Since that moment my jenkins jobs are failing at the compile stage itself. Below is the error i'm getting from jenkins console.

```
  /Users/jenkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Companion- 
  dtiiwydzoavsrybgsztwqribsxtx/Build/Products/Release- 
  iphoneos/sample.app/Frameworks/KSCrash.framework: 
  errSecInternalComponent
  Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code


** BUILD FAILED **


 The following build commands failed:
PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Embed\ Pods\ Frameworks 
/Users/jenkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Companion- 
dtiiwydzoavsrybgsztwqribsxtx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/
Companion.build/Release- 
iphoneos/SampleProject.build/Script-15FB268A228A7C3900925F65.sh
```

Do i need to add that new certificate some where else ? What might be the issue ? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has solved my problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/52221673/1025976.

Solution for errSecInternalComponent error is : Go to Keychain -> My Certificates -> Select your Development or Distribution certficiate -> Expand it and double click on the private key -> Select "Allow all applications to access them" and save changes. This should solve the problem.