# Unable to build app when connected to physical device

Tags: ios, swift, certificate

After building my app to a physical device and archiving my build I get an error message and my app won't build to a physical device. I receive the following error message:

XXX.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework with Identity Apple Development: XXX
XXX.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework'
XXX.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework: errSecInternalComponent
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

I have tried cleaning build folder, downloaded certificates again but to no success.
Does anyone know something that can help?

Comment: Did you try these solutions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24023639/xcode-command-usr-bin-codesign-failed-with-exit-code-1-errsecinternalcomponen

Answer (score 0):

Please provide further information. Are you using cocoapod or carthage or dependencies ?
If you build the project and get the framework yourself without make it a "fat" framework, It only works on the stimulator or physical device only.

Comment: I use Cocoapods. It used to work on my device. Thinking it may be related to signing somehow?