# Flutter deployment error when testing on physical device: : errSecInternalComponent

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart, flutter-test

I am trying to test my flutter application on my iPad, and iPhone, and I have tried everything that I've read from forums.
It will run on an emulator, but not a physical device.

I have tried:
Cleaning and rebuilding.
Restarting my computer.
Updating all of the software on both my computer and the devices. 
Creating a unique bundle id.
Choosing different teams for signing.
Changing iOS development target.
Changing the bundle id to my email.

I'm just not sure what to fix at this point.

this is the output of flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 1.19.0-4.0.pre.108, on Mac OS X 10.15.5 19F101, locale en-US)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.5)
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.45.1)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Have you read through https://stackoverflow.com/q/24023639/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something up with Xcode and my computer, because I downgraded to Xcode 11.3 and it worked.