# How to resolve error of "errSecInternalComponent" while building archive for appstore?

Tags: ios, flutter, app-store, app-store-connect

I am trying to submit flutter app to Appstore. Here are the steps I followed:

Deleted all certificates and provisioning profiles

Create/Add IOS Distribution Certificate

Create IOS Provisioning Profile

Add IOS Provisioning Profile

Clean App

Build Then Run App

Set Codesigning and Provisioning Profile In Build Settings

Lots of Googling > to no successes

Basically, facing the error of "errSecInternalComponent"

Here is the error I get:

```
 Warning: unable to build chain to self-signed root for signer "iPhone Distribution: Johnny  (**********)"
    /Users/johnny/Downloads/chat_app-master 2/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks/App.framework/App: errSecInternalComponent
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are having an issue with a certificate, that's why you get this warning. You need to generate a new one.

Try this:
xcode -> preferences -> accounts -> select the account  -> manage certificate -> click on the (+) icon in the bottom left side of the popup window -> ios development

Comment: it doesn't give option for iOS development , it gives option for Apple Development, how should I proceed?

Comment: Add Apple Development should work as well. Make sure on the iOS device you go to the General -> Device Management -> and click your account ...

Answer (score 1):

Build the first time with Xcode, Xcode will ask you to update the keychain, click on always allow.
After that, your command line build will work.

Answer (score 1):

For me the following worked - even from a ssh session:

```
security unlock-keychain -p "<my password>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the issue is already resolved, this might not be the answer to you.
However, I would like to share this with the community as I stumbled upon the same error message with another setup.

I have been building an iOS App with Xcode on a MacMini used as gitlab runner.
Building the app manually worked, but whenever I pushed to the repository and the automated build started, this error appeared.

Updating the ruby version to a higher version than BigSur's shipped one and reinstalling the gitlab-runner resolved my issue.