# X Code failing to archive flutter project

Tags: xcode, flutter, build

I have a flutter projects which runs smoothly in IOS simulators. But when I try to build archive it keeps failing with error

```
sent 417348630 bytes  received 120 bytes  166939500.00 bytes/sec
total size is 417297279  speedup is 1.00
/Users/blb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner- grwmtliatfewpwgywhanjiefmgxn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Runner.app/Frameworks/App.framework/App: errSecInternalComponent
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

I have all the developer certificates and accounts etc. Tried every solution I found in internet but didn't worked.

```
blb@Bhargavs-MacBook-Pro customer % flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, 1.25.0-8.3.pre, on macOS 11.1 20C69 darwin-x64, locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 1.25.0-8.3.pre at /Users/blb/Development/flutter
    • Framework revision 5d36f2e7f5 (3 days ago), 2021-01-14 15:57:49 -0800
    • Engine revision 7a8f8ca02c
    • Dart version 2.12.0 (build 2.12.0-133.7.beta)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/blb/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.3, Build version 12C33
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.51.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.16.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • Redmi Note 7 Pro (mobile)           • a682ccfc                             • android-arm64  • Android 10 (API 29)
    • iPhone SE (2nd generation) (mobile) • 2FEBA15E-A172-4FF2-B915-ECF8D222F57A • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-3 (simulator)
    • Chrome (web)                        • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 87.0.4280.141

• No issues found!
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24023639/xcode-command-usr-bin-codesign-failed-with-exit-code-1-errsecinternalcomponen

Answer (score 0):

It might be related to a singing issue.
I was facing the same issue where the app was forking fine when I did

```
flutter run // Working
```

But when I tried creating the ipa for distribution, it used to give me an archive failed error.

```
flutter build ipa  // Error
```

I tried to do flutter clean, xcode clean and all the other different things but nothing worked.

So, I tried with a sample app, and then ran flutter build ipa which asked me to setup my certificate on that project which I did and it worked fine.

When, I came back to my original project, and it also started working. So, it was definitely some certificate issue which was leading to all these problems. Using a sample project, helped resolve it.