# codesign fails with errSecInternalComponent: unable to build chain to self-signed root for signer

Tags: macos, code-signing

I am trying to sign my app with `codesign`, but it fails with "errSecInternalComponent":

```
❯ codesign --force --deep --sign "Apple Development: ..." my.app
Warning: unable to build chain to self-signed root for signer "Apple Development: ..."
my.app: errSecInternalComponent
```

I tried to solve the problem like [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24023639) by going to KeyChain and locking all keychains and repeating the process: it asks for the keychain password, but then it still fails with the same error.

A few preliminary checks:

- I already added my apple id to xcode
- I created an "Apple Development Certificate"
- if I go to KeyChain I see the certificate amongst the others, however it says that it is not trusted.

however if I run in terminal: `security find-identity -v -p codesigning` I get: "0 valid identities found"

I tried to remove the Apple Developer certificate from KeyChain, and download it again from developer.apple.com, and reinstalling it, but I get the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out two certificates were missing:

- [Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certificate Authority](https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer)
- [Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certificate Authority G3](https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/AppleWWDRCAG3.cer)

after downloading and installing those, the `security find-identity` command would return one entry, and code signing would succeed.

Comment: How did you find exactly these 2 were missing ?

Comment: Random trial and error plus info found on the net. These tools offer no useful diagnostics unfortunately.

Comment: I have found this post.  I have applied the two certs.  When I run "security find-identity" i get myself listed, so I think that is right.  However, I am having no success on this.