# Developer ID Application Certificate missing a child key in Keychain Access

Tags: macos, code-signing, codesign, code-signing-certificate

I am trying to recreate a Developer ID Application certificate, so I can sign my application. I had an existing certificate, but it's about to expire, so I am trying to regenerate a new one.

However, when I download a newly generated certificate from developer.apple.com, the imported certificate has no key as its child node in Keychain Access. The old certificate had this. When I attempt to use the certificate for code signing I receive something like:

```
/tmp/myapp.app/Contents/app/bin/myapp.exe: errSecInternalComponent
```

I am following the [instructions to obtain a signed certificate using Certificate Assistant](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Procedures/Procedures.html):

1. Ensuring nothing is selected in Keychain Access, click Keychain Access > Certificate Assistant > Request a Certificate from a Certificate Authority.
2. I enter my email, accept the default *Common Name* and click *Saved to disk*.
3. In developer.apple.com I click the "+" to *Create a New Certificate*
4. I choose *Developer ID Application*
5. I upload the CSR I saved above
6. I download the `.cer` file that is generated
7. I open the `.cer` file. This adds the certificate.

As you can see, the certificate does not have a private key inside it, like the old one:

[image]

Unfortunately I don't have the old certificate now having deleted it in a fit of pique but it looked like this:

[image]

... although in my case it had my private key.

I've noticed reference to the claim that creating a CSR also creates a public/private key pair, but I cannot see these anywhere in Keychain Access.

*Later*, I did manage to import the certificate and it show the private key. I think this was when I imported it into the same keychain as that which contains a private key "Dan Gravell" - *login*. However, I have since tried replicating that and now the certificate is being imported without a key again.

#### Xcode appearance

I've discovered there's a little more information in Xcode. The certificate shows "Missing Private Key" next to it:

[image]

When I look this error up, the suggestions seem to be that the certificate has been given to a developer by some third party that didn't include the private key. However, in my case I *am* that third party who has created the CSR and received the certificate originally and *I thought I had the private key, otherwise I wouldn't have been able to create the CSR in the first place*. All these items appear to be in my keychain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I (eventually) got a reply from Developer Program Support. They issued a new certificate which I installed via XCode this time. I documented my other steps here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74210449/28190